# Possible to use NSUrlSession (in Xamarin) to download files in the background in Azure Mobile Apps?

Tags: ios, background, xamarin.ios, azure-mobile-services, nsurlsession

I want to leverage [iOS background file downloads](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW5) in Azure Mobile Apps using Monotouch/Xamarin.

I'm unable to determine if this is how the Xamarin implementation (PCL) currently works, is possible through a platform-specific implementation, or needs to become a feature request.

I've attempted to look for the Git source to see if this implementation is present in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Sync, but I'm unable to locate it.

Comment: Your remote most probably needs to accept ranges:  `Accept-ranges: bytes` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Ranges, otherwise i don't see how download resume is possible. Other than that i don't think there's any special sauce needed on the remote.

Comment: @evilSnobu I was thinking this was a client SDK issue, but that server comment is something to look into

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the Azure Mobile Apps File Sync for iOS/Swift/Objective-C, it does not exist yet, and won't exist for some time.

You are better off looking at the iOS SDK for Azure Storage and upload/download to an Azure Storage Account.  The only addition you will need is a SAS token generator API, which will be a custom API in your backend.  You can use Azure Mobile Apps for this purpose, or just a straight ExpressJS or ASP.NET WebAPI.

Comment: The FIles support is beta and is not being actively worked right now.  See https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-files-client for the client impl. and https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-files-server for the server impl.  There is also a blog post on azure.com